# Fragment layout and Action Bar is showing repeatedly when it is selected

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have created a listview as a menu that will show you a specific fragment when selected. The problem is, if you select another option from the menu, the fragment will not clear, instead, it will just show another fragment. It's overlapping with other fragments that were previously selected.

How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: No one can tell you how you can fix it? You question is vague no details no codes are added.
You should read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please check my answer. - @BeverlyCastillo

Answer (score 0):

When you click on a particular item from the list that time `replace` your fragment and set the white background in `xml` file.

Please try below code :

```
FragmentTransaction ft = null;
HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.flHome, fragment).commit();
```

And `clear` the menu in onCreateOptionMenu

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     menu.clear();
     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.game_menu, menu);
     return true;
}
```